# XSLT Identity Transform doesn't copy all attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have following code for XSL transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That's the standard sample of identity transformation. For most cases it works just right. But I was able to find a case when it doesn't copy properly. For following XML code:

```
<c xmlns:x="x">
    <a xmlns:x="x"/>
</c>
```

the transformed xml code looks following:

```
<c xmlns:x="x"><a /></c>
```

If you remove namespaces `xmlns` from XML code, then it starts working properly. Also, if you change name of the second argument (leaving `xmlns` namespace), you have proper identity transformation. I'm stuck, because I can't explain WHY using same argument with this exact same namespace makes such troubles.

BTW, you can reproduce those errors on https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html webpage.

Comment: The two results are semantically identical. The indenting depends on your processor - see for example a different result here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq75 You can control the indenting to some extent by using`<xsl:output indent="yes"/>` and/or the `xsl:strip-space` and `xsl:preserve-space` instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, an element's declared namespace prefix, `xmlns:x="x"`, matching the *same* namespace prefix and URI as its parent is redundant. And the XSLT processing removes this redundancy. Both are essentially the same XML content.

According to the W3C rules on [Namespaces in XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/) (emphasis added):

> If the attribute name matches PrefixedAttName, then the NCName gives
>   the namespace prefix, used to associate element and attribute names
>   with the namespace name in the attribute value **in the scope of the
>   element** to which the declaration is attached.
>   
> ...
>   An example namespace declaration, which associates the namespace
>   prefix edi with the namespace name `http://ecommerce.org/schema`:
>
> ```
> <x xmlns:edi='http://ecommerce.org/schema'>
>   <!-- the "edi" prefix is bound to http://ecommerce.org/schema
>        for the "x" element and contents -->
> </x>
> ```

Specifically with your use case, the *x* namespace prefix is already defined in the scope of `<c>` so `<a>` (being the child element) can use the `x` namespace prefix anywhere in its contents without another declaration. So your original content:

```
<c xmlns:x="x">
    <a xmlns:x="x"/>
</c>
```

Is identical to XSLT output:

```
<c xmlns:x="x"><a/></c>
```

Or with line breaks and indents as mentioned in comments by @michael.hor257k.

```
<c xmlns:x="x">
    <a/>
</c>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was totally stuck because of that.

Comment: It's technically not even the XSLT processor that removes the redundant namespace declaration: it's the processor/parser that constructs the XDM input to the XSLT processor. XSLT is defined to operate on a data model, XDM, which provides no way of representing information about redundant namespace declarations.